# my URL is giving 404 on my defined ROUTE

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in netbeans
I've controller named Cms with a function signup in which I load the view as

```
$this -> load -> view('cms/signup');
```

and view is on the followoing location

`D:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\application\views\cms`
in the routes.php I've defined the following route to access this view

```
$route['aaa'] = 'cms/signup';
```

when I type the following URL http://roz.com/cms/aaa it says CI error message "page not found" yesterday it was working. default controller is working fine without index.php with following URL `'http://roz.com/cms'`
please advice where the problem lies actually. I am working on localhost

Comment: the link you provided redirects to homepage

Comment: With the available information, i would advice you check the `.htaccess` file that you probably wrote to remove the `index.php` off the link

Comment: you have not shown any controller code apart from the loading of the view, so this is just a guess... Have you got your method set as private or protected, this would prevent it being accessed by the route? The problem may be the .htaccess as suggested by ISuthan Bala. But if it was all working yesterday i would suggest checking your code for things that have changed!